# NGINX config proxy_set_header

Tags: configuration, nginx

How configurate nginx to set `proxy_set_header` for all domains, but not for everyone?

Comment: What's the problem to define it at `http` level?

Answer (score 7):

I include a global proxy configuration (e.g. `/etc/nginx/conf.d/02_proxy.conf`) at the end of Nginx's main configuration file (`/etc/nginx/nginx.conf`):

```
...

events {
  worker_connections 1024;
  use epoll;
}

http {
  include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
  default_type application/octet-stream;

  ...

  include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
  include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}
```

From the [Nginx documentation](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_set_header):

> The `proxy_set_header` directives are inherited from the previous level if and only if there are no proxy_set_header directives defined on the current level.

This means you can use a custom header on the `server` or `location` level to overwrite all global headers:

```
server {

  ...

  proxy_set_header X-RESET-CUSTOM-HEADERS true;

  ...
}
```

---

If you use additional `proxy_set_header` on the `server` or `location` level  and want to keep the global ones, you must import this file again on that level.

Comment: This has literally been evading me for years, thank you so much.  I never realized until now that `proxy_set_header` had weird inheritance rules.

Answer (score 1):

Just put your `proxy_set_header` in your `http` block and not only in your server or location block.

> proxy_set_header syntax: proxy_set_header header value;
>
> default: Host and Connection
>
> **context: http**, server, location